# NSLayoutConstraint error with a irrational number multiplier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using the [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to implement an `UITableViewCell` with an `UIImageView` inside. I want to make their edges exactly coincide (obviously they should have the same size).

And, I'm using the Auto-height Cell in iOS9.2 / iPhone 6:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
```

This is what I do:

```
[_imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    // The aspect ratio of the imageView is certain
    make.width.equalTo(_imageView.mas_height).multipliedBy(3.6f);
    make.edges.equalTo(self.contentView);
}];
```

But I got an error said (I delete the memory address for you reading easily):

```
(
"... UIImageView.width == UIImageView.height * 3.6>",
"... UIImageView.left == UITableViewCellContentView.left>",
"... UIImageView.right == UITableViewCellContentView.right>",
"... UIImageView.top == UITableViewCellContentView.top>",
"... UIImageView.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView.bottom>",
"... UITableViewCellContentView.height == 104>",
"... UITableViewCellContentView.width == 375>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<... UIImageView.width == UIImageView.height * 3.6>
```

But,

```
375 / 104 = 3.605769230769231... ≈ 3.6
```

When I change the multiplier to some `3.75` or `2`, it's all correct.

So what should I do to get away from this error and why this happen?